# how to implement callback system

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a class system that uses callbacks to notify of certain events. I can think of 2 ways to do this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A(std::function<void(int)>&& func) : f(std::move(func)) {}
    void run() { f(2); }
    std::function<void(int)> f;
};

template <class F>
class B {
public:
    B(F&& func) : f(std::move(func)) {}
    void run() { f(2); }
    F f;
};

int main() {
    int n = 1;
    A a1([n](int b){std::cout << n+b << '\n';});
    B b1([n](int b){std::cout << n+b << '\n';});
    a1.run();
    b1.run();
}
```

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using these 2 approaches (having a template type for the callback type vs. using std::function)

Answer (score 2):

I think it boils down to whether you can afford to have templated `B` because `F` can spread through your code quite quickly. Consider:

```cpp
struct Foo{
    B<???> member;
};
```

If `B` is used mostly locally, `F` is fixed, or `F` should be exposed through `Foo`, this second approach can do everything that `A` can and doesn't have the overhead of `std::function`. (Measure!)

If you cannot afford that, you will need some form of type erasure, a.k.a `std::function`. But `std::variant` could be handy too.

I mean if you go with `std::function`, which has fixed signature, abstract callable `Event` class with `virtual void operator()(int)` is a viable option too. Well, without the lambdas, or with `LambdaEvent` using `std::function` underneath. Still this event hiearchy might provide more "type safety".

Please note that as written, B can accept any callable, not just `void(int)`.
Consider using `std::invoke(f,2)` instead of `f(2)`.